# X axis vs Y axis Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, canvas, bitmap

I drew a perfect large square in canvas and then split that large square into 15x15 smaller squares.

Now I am moving a bitmap using an image along X and Y Axis. The bitmap is of same size as the smaller square.

It moves along X axis perfectly one square at a time. But it covers more than one square along Y axis. So I have to multiply by approximately 0.93 to get to the size of the smaller square. But the problem is that it gets more complicated with different devices cellphone vs tablet.

Does anybody know why Y axis is different from X axis?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the displays have a slightly different densities between the X and Y axis, using my device and running the following command:

```
adb shell dumpsys display
```

searching for "density", I got the result:

```
 PhysicalDisplayInfo{1080 x 2280, 60.000004 fps, density 3.0, 442.451 x 438.727 dpi, secure true, appVsyncOffset 0, bufferDeadline 17666666}
```

Depending on how you're declaring your square that may be the cause.